# AutoMapper: What is the difference between MapFrom and ResolveUsing?

Tags: automapper, automapper-2

Ignoring the `ResolveUsing` overloads that take an IValueResolver, and looking only at these 2 methods:

```cs
void ResolveUsing(Func<TSource, object> resolver);
void MapFrom<TMember>(Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> sourceMember);
```

The main difference between these 2 seems to be that `ResolveUsing` takes a `Func<TSource, object>`, whereas MapFrom takes an `Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>>`.

However in client code that actually uses one of these methods with a lambda expression, they seem to be interchangeable:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestType>() // uses ResolveUsing
   .ForMember(d => d.DestPropX, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.SourcePropY));

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestType>() // uses MapFrom
   .ForMember(d => d.DestPropX, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SourcePropY));
```

So what ultimately is the difference between the above 2 choices? Is one faster than the other? Is one a better choice than the other and if so, when / why?

Comment: This question simply fixed my another problem.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In the past I had a [long email exchange on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/automapper-users/zx9pd18vcVQ) with the author of Automapper. MapFrom will do null checks all the way trough the expression:

> So you can do `opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
>   src.SomeProp.Way.Down.Here.Somewhere)` and each level will get checked
>   for nulls (as it already does for flattening).

Comment: Info from that link: `MapFrom` is intended for redirecting source members - things like `ForMember(dest => dest.Foo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Bar))`. `MapFrom` has all of the null-checking that flattening has, so it can be thought of as redirecting the flattening algorithm. `ResolveUsing` is for pretty much anything else, any additional custom logic beyond member access. It's a `Func<>` instead of an `Expression<Func<>>`, so you don't get null checking.

Comment: [This link](http://blog.travisgosselin.com/automapper-mapfrom-vs-resolveusing/) explains some of the potential performance hits that can be seen when using `MapFrom` when nulls properties are often expected in your application.

Comment: When you're using a method as part of the mapping such as `src.PropA.Select(x => x...)`. If PropA is null then you get an exception. Use ResolveUsing in that scenario

Comment: Perhaps you should also note that this is only possible when using simple expressions, as soon as you add a { block of code } the automatic null checking is no longer possible.

Comment: From automapper 8.0, ResovleUsing was replaced by MapFrom. [updgrate guide](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolveusing)

Comment: Perhaps this is over-generalized but, with `MapFrom`, you get automatic safety checks, while with `ResolveUsing`, you must provide your own. If you know for sure you'll be dealing with nulls, `ResolveUsing` can be faster. Of course, since AutoMapper 8, `ResolveUsing` is no longer available.

Answer (score 23):

I just did some benchmarks using the new C# 6 [null conditional operator](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2014/12/csharp-6-null-conditional-operators.html#Od0vxZ2szcDFvc0y.97) `?.`

Consider the following scenario: class `A` has a child class `B`, which has a child `C`, whose `Name` property we want to flatten into a DTO. I tested two variants:

```
// using mapfrom
CreateMap<MapFromA, MapFromADto>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Name, o => o.MapFrom(a => a.B.C.Name));

// using resolveusing with elvis
CreateMap<ResolveUsingX, ResolveUsingXDto>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Name, o => o.ResolveUsing(x => x.Y?.Z?.Name));
```

I called `_mapper.Map<ResolveUsingXDto>(x);` or `_mapper.Map<MapFromADto>(a);` for 1000 different `ResolveUsingX x` and `MapFromA a` and took the time using a `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch`. Here are my results:

```
Distinct elements per batch: 1000; # batches for average: 25

A->B->C.Name, C is never null.
MapForm - average time taken for 1000x: 5527,84 ticks = 1,44 ms.
ResolveUsing - average time taken for 1000x: 5479,76 ticks =  1,4 ms.

A->B->C.Name, C is null 1/3 of the time.
MapForm - average time taken for 1000x: 72924,4 ticks = 27,44 ms.
ResolveUsing - average time taken for 1000x: 5351,2 ticks =  1,48 ms.

A->B->C.Name, C is null 1/2 of the time.
MapForm - average time taken for 1000x: 107016,92 ticks = 40,52 ms.
ResolveUsing - average time taken for 1000x: 5835,32 ticks =  1,56 ms.

A->B->C.Name, C is null 2/3 of the time.
MapForm - average time taken for 1000x: 141437,96 ticks = 53,64 ms.
ResolveUsing - average time taken for 1000x: 5789,72 ticks =  1,56 ms.
```

`MapFrom` has to catch NullReferenceExceptions, which is slower than `ResolveUsing` with the elvis operator `?.`

Comment: +1 This was a very useful benchmark. It shows the difference between exception handling and explicit null-checking. Hopefully, the new versions of AutoMapper use explicit null-checking, since `ResolveUsing` is no longer available.

Answer (score 9):

`MapFrom` has [a few extra smarts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/automapper-users/TO5Re0vpems). For example (from the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/automapper-users/AekQJdepzU8/uwmsIhLTpZoJ)):

> In MapFrom, I try to be smart about digging in to child properties (much like the normal flattening does). MapFrom is an attempt to mimic flattening, with an added bit of allowing redirection.
>   ResolveUsing doesn't have this behavior.

I'm not sure if this is fully [documented](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) anywhere (apart from in the [source code](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)).

Comment: So then it seems as long as you are mapping scalars and not complex objects, they are functionally the same. I wonder if `ResolveUsing` is faster because of the extra smarts in MapFrom.....?

Comment: Possibly, although I don't think any official performance tests have been done. If its important enough for you, it shouldn't take you long to set up a couple of tests for your particular scenario.

Comment: Not that important. I just have calls all over where one or the other is used, with no real consistency. Wanted to become less ignorant about it, so posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

Although in many situations either can be used, based on [official documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) there is a difference when it comes to LINQ projections. Detailed explanation can be found [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/12/30/automapper-3-3-feature-parameterized-projections/).

Long story short: use MapFrom whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code, `ResolveUsing` is more complicated. The source value can be any object; therefore, you can use any value you want to fill the destination member, such as int or bool that you get by "Resolving" the given object. However, `MapFrom` only uses member to map from.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Resolve destination member using a custom value resolver callback. Used instead of MapFrom when not simply redirecting a source member
/// This method cannot be used in conjunction with LINQ query projection
/// </summary>
/// <param name="resolver">Callback function to resolve against source type</param>
void ResolveUsing(Func<TSource, object> resolver);

/// <summary>
/// Specify the source member to map from. Can only reference a member on the <typeparamref name="TSource"/> type
/// This method can be used in mapping to LINQ query projections, while ResolveUsing cannot.
/// Any null reference exceptions in this expression will be ignored (similar to flattening behavior)
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TMember">Member type of the source member to use</typeparam>
/// <param name="sourceMember">Expression referencing the source member to map against</param>
void MapFrom<TMember>(Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> sourceMember);
```