# Automapper: Checking for null in MapFrom

Tags: c#, automapper, null-check

Using version 4.

How do I check for null when doing a map? I tried the `.Value`, but that's not there on a `Null`:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Agenda, AgendaViewModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.DateApproved, 
               y => y.MapFrom(s =>  DateTime.SpecifyKind(s.DateApproved.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc)));
```

Comment: `s.DateApproved.HasValue` maybe ?

Comment: Check this, use ResolveUsing solution for the better performance of the code:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/35972650/1559611

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alternatively, you can just check the `HasValue` property prior to mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Agenda, AgendaViewModel>()
     .ForMember(x => x.DateApproved,
                y => y.MapFrom(s => s.DateApproved.HasValue ?
                                    DateTime.SpecifyKind(s.DateApproved.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc) :
                                    DateTime.UtcNow));
```

Comment: Is z.DateApproved.HasValue same as null check, can't we do simple null check here

Comment: For such scenario ResolveUsing would be a preferred call

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Agenda, AgendaViewModel>()
        .ForMember(x => x.DateApproved, 
                    y => y.ResolveUsing(z => z.DateApproved.HasValue 
                           ? DateTime.UtcNow :
                           Mapper.Map<Agenda, AgendaViewModel>
                          (DateTime.SpecifyKind(z.DateApproved.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc)));
```

Comment: Is z.DateApproved.HasValue same as null check, can't we do simple null check here

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Compiler will convert `== null` to .`HasValue` for Nullable types. So it is the same.