# How can I add custom logic in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following code.

All of the fields map nicely from the source to the destination object.

However, there is one field in the destination object that I will need to compute.

For example:

`DestinationObj.Status` can be set depending on certain fields from the `SourceObj`.

If I were to write code, it would look similar to:

```
foreach (var rec in listData)
{
    string status;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rec.Field1))
    {
        status = "Stage 1";
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rec.Field2))
    {
        status = "Stage 2";
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rec.Field3))
    {
        status = "Stage 3";
    }
}
```

Can I do something similar in AutoMapper?

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
{
    c.CreateMap<SourceObj, DestinationObj>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Status, m => m.MapFrom([Not sure at this point]));
});
```

EDIT:

```
List<destinationObj> destinObj = new List<destinationObj>();

foreach (var rec in listSourceObject)
{
    destinationObj do = new destinationObj();
    // Manually map all of the fields...

    string status;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rec.Field1))
    {
        do.status = "Stage 1";
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rec.Field2))
    {
        do.status = "Stage 2";
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rec.Field3))
    {
        do.status = "Stage 3";
    }

    destinObj.Add(do);
}
```

Comment: Where does `listData` come from? Where does `status` go? The method you want to apply doesn't appear to relate to your mapping at all.

Comment: I cleaned up code in edit.

Comment: It still isn't that clear. Are both objects a collection of themselves....?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to move your method into your mapper class. You can then access that method within your `.MapFrom()`.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
{
    c.CreateMap<SourceObj, DestinationObj>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => MapStatus(src)));

});

private string MapStatus(SourceObject source)
{
    // Whatever that foreach loop actually does.
}
```

For more info, see [Custom Value Resolvers](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html#custom-value-resolvers)

Answer (score 3):

Suggested solutions with `MapFrom()` and workarounds for expressions are not entirely correct. `MapFrom()` (as [AutoMapper: What is the difference between MapFrom and ResolveUsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875075/automapper-what-is-the-difference-between-mapfrom-and-resolveusing) suggests) is smarter, so it can handle nested `PropertyExpression`s.

To handle regular functions for mapping values, you should use `ResolveUsing()`, which accepts a `Func<>`, so you can enter the code directly and there is no need to modify the call to be expressed as `Expression<Func<>>`.

Comment: Since [version 8](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolveusing), `ResolveUsing` has been consolidated with `MapFrom`.  You now have an overload that takes a `Func<>`.